# Laravel consultas anidadas, como hacer una consulta de tres tablas

Tags: laravel

Tengo tres tablas relacionadas asi: TablaUno relacionada de uno a muchos con Tabla2, Tabla2 relacionada de uno a muchos con TablaTres.

Como puedo hacer una consulta de datos de la TablaTres con una condición hacia la Tabla1. La verdad soy nuevo en Laravel y no tengo mucha idea de lo que tengo que hacer.

Intente algo así, pero ovio no funciono.

```
return view('tabla3.index')
            ->with('TablaTres', $TablaTres -> where('id_tabla1', '4'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias hacer uso inner join:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

checa la docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Answer (score 0):

Si la condición depende de la tabla uno, es decir, es sobre sus campos, tienes que hacer la condición sobre esa tabla y sobre el resultado obtener las relaciones hacia la tabla 2 y de ahí a la tabla 3, o no se si puedas poner mas información sobre los campos y la condición